# Labeled TextBox in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, win-universal-app

I'm trying to realize a labeled `TextBox` in a windows universal app using *C#* and *XAML*, but I did not get the value of the `TextBox` in return, just empty string.

The code of my **generic.xaml** for it looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="template:LabeledTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="template:LabeledTextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" />
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Value}" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The control looks like this:

```
public sealed class LabeledTextBox : Control, IParameterReturnable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    public string Label
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(LabelProperty).ToString(); }
        set { this.SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(ValueProperty).ToString(); }
        set { this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsReadOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(false));
    public string IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty).ToString(); }
        set { this.SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
    }

    public LabeledTextBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(LabeledTextBox);
    }

    public LabeledTextBox(Parameter parameter)
    {
        this.Label = parameter.DisplayName;
        this.Value = parameter.DefaultValue ?? "";
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(LabeledTextBox);
    }

    public string GetKey()
    {
        return this.Label;
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
}
```

You are free to ignore my *IParameterReturnable*, which I am using to access to `GetKey()` and `GetValue()` while looping through different types of these labeled-controls.

So what am I missing, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for all helpful and well meant answers!

**EDIT: Code for adding Control**

The control is added dynamically with C# like this:

```
foreach (Parameter parameter in parameters)
{
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new LabeledTextBox(parameter));
}
```

But it would looks like this in Xaml:

```
<templates:LabeledTextBox Label="[Label]" Value="[Value]" IsReadOnly="False" />
```

It will be read out like this:

```
foreach(IParameterReturnable parameter in stackPanel.Children)
{
    string val = parameter.GetValue() // <= this will always return the default value
}
```

Comment: can you share the xaml where you are placing LabeledTextBox

Comment: for the special situation where I loop through these, the controls are dynamically added to a stackpanel by c# and not by xaml

Comment: so how are you setting the Label & Text Properties? can you add the code to question then.

Comment: Entry is updated with code

Comment: If you don't use the `Tag` property, you can use it for displaying the label without the need of extending the `TextBox` control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the `Value` property with a new value from your templated `TextBox`.

In your `generic.xaml` add a name to your `TextBox`: `<TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"...`

Then your `LabeledTextBox` class should look like this:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TextBox", Type = typeof(TextBox))]
public sealed class LabeledTextBox : Control, IParameterReturnable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    public string Label
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(LabelProperty).ToString(); }
        set { this.SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(ValueProperty).ToString(); }
        set { this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsReadOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(LabeledTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(false));
    public string IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty).ToString(); }
        set { this.SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
    }

    public LabeledTextBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(LabeledTextBox);
    }

    private TextBox _textBox;

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _textBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as TextBox;

        if (_textBox != null)
        {
            _textBox.TextChanged += TextBoxOnTextChanged;
        }
    }

    private void TextBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs)
    {
        this.Value = _textBox.Text;
    }

    public LabeledTextBox(Parameter parameter)
    {
        this.Label = parameter.DisplayName;
        this.Value = parameter.DefaultValue ?? "";
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(LabeledTextBox);
    }

    public string GetKey()
    {
        return this.Label;
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
}
```

Notice that I have added the `TemplatePart` attribute and overriden the `OnApplyTemplate` in which I register for the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox`. When the text changes, I update the `Value` dependency property.

Comment: Maybe I am free to ask you right here: How should a static Dependency looks like, when I got a LabeledComboBox and want to bind the SelectionChanged-Event?

Comment: I added my question in a new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521254/labeled-combobox-in-windows-10-universal-app