# Labeled ComboBox in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, win-universal-app

similar to my Labeled TextBox, which issues are resolved in:

[Labeled TextBox in Windows Universal App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512469/labeled-textbox-in-windows-universal-app)

I got two issues in my Labeled Combobox, but first the Code:

**Generic.xaml**:

```
<Style TargetType="template:LabeledComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="template:LabeledComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" />
                    <ComboBox x:Name="PART_ComboBox" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" SelectedIndex="{TemplateBinding SelectedIndex}" SelectedValue="{TemplateBinding SelectedValue}" SelectedValuePath="{TemplateBinding SelectedValuePath}" DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**LabeledComboBox.cs**:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ComboBox", Type = typeof(ComboBox))]
public sealed class LabeledComboBox : Control, IParameterReturnable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(""));
    public string Label
    {
        get { return GetValue(LabelProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(LabeledComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(LabeledComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(object), typeof(LabeledComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object SelectedValue
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValuePathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValuePath", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    public string SelectedValuePath
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedValuePathProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValuePathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(LabeledComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
    public string DisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
    }

    private ComboBox _comboBox;

    public LabeledComboBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(LabeledComboBox);
    }

    public LabeledComboBox(List<Parameter> parameterList)
    {
        this.Label = parameterList[0].DisplayName ?? "";
        this.ItemsSource = parameterList;
        this.SelectedValuePath = "DefaultValue";
        this.DisplayMemberPath = "DefaultValue";
        this.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(LabeledComboBox);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _comboBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_ComboBox") as ComboBox;

        if (_comboBox != null)
        {
            _comboBox.SelectionChanged += OnComboBoxSelectionChanged;
            if (_comboBox.Items != null)
            {
                this.SelectedIndex = 0;
                _comboBox.SelectedValue = _comboBox.Items[this.SelectedIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedValue = _comboBox.SelectedValue;
    }

    public string GetKey()
    {
        return Label;
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        return SelectedValue.ToString();
    }

}
```

It will be called in two different ways:

**Dynamically in C#**:

```
stackPanel.Add(new LabeledComboBox(parameterList));
```

**Static in Xaml**:

```
<templates:LabeledComboBox Label="Kategorien:" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=FeedCategories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

As I said before I got two issues with it:

1. How can I bind the SelectionChangedEvent to access it in Xaml || C#
2. As you can see, I try to preselect the first Item, which does not work and I don't know how to do it right

Thank you very much for all helpful and well meant answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a custom control and recreating all needed dependency properties, I would suggest you use the `Header` and `HeaderTemplate` properties of the built in `ComboBox`, which will be displayed, just like in your `LabeledComboBox`, above the selection menu. Additionally the `SelectionChanged` event will be available.

So the usage in XAML would look like the following:

```
    <ComboBox
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        Header="Kategorien:"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=FeedCategories}"
        SelectedValuePath="Name"
        SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="10,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.HeaderTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

But if you don't want to use the above method, to expose the selection changed event in your `LabeledComboBox`, add the following code:

```
    private void OnComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedValue = _comboBox.SelectedValue;
        this.RaiseSelectionChanged(e);
    }

    public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectionChanged;

    private void RaiseSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (SelectionChanged != null)
        {
            SelectionChanged(this, args);
        }
    }
```

Then you can use the created `SelectionChanged` event from XAML.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfect for me! And thank you for the Xaml advice, I didn't know that something like this is possible, I will keep it in mind, but for the dynamic adding I finished the C#-Code!